# Number of one -to-one functions

Tags: functions

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $B = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$. what is the number of functions  from $A$ to $B$ are either one-to-one or map the element $1$ to $c$?
My answer is $166$, but I'm not really sure of my approach .

To calculate $A \cup B = 5! + 4^3 - 4$!

Comment: What is your approach?

Comment: I think $4^3$ must be $5^3$ here.

Comment: This looks like it would use an application of [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Show us what you have done so we can help.

Comment: @barakmanos: any function that maps $1$ to $c$ and $\{2,3,4\}$ to $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ should be counted.

Comment: @robjohn: I don't understand this statement.

Comment: @barakmanos  The number of functions that map $1$ to $c$ is $5^3$ since $2$, $3$, and $4$ can each be mapped to any of the five elements in set $B$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Oh yep, that's right, my bad...

Answer (score 6):

number of functions from $A$ to $B$ that are one-to-one: $5\times4\times3\times2=120$

number of functions from $A$ to $B$ that map $1$ to $c$: $5^{3}=125$

number of functions from $A$ to $B$ that are one-to-one AND map
$1$ to $c$: $4\times3\times2=24$

number of functions from $A$ to $B$ that are one-to-one OR map $1$
to $c$: $120+125-24=221$ (inclusion/exclusion)

Comment: The OP had "either – or"; so maybe the correct answer is $(120-24)+(125-24)=197$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thank you. My English is not good enough to judge about that. I trust that the OP will react on this if you are right.

Answer (score 2):

$5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2 = 120$ one-to-one maps,

$5^3 = 125$ functions that each maps $1 \to c$,

$4\cdot 3\cdot 2 = 24$ maps that are one-to-one and map $1\to c$. Thus:

$|A\cup B| = |A|+|B| -|A\cap B| =120+125-24 = 221$ maps by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: You might want to mention the principle of inclusion-exclusion to show how you got your answer.